# Inserting a data in a table that comes from another table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, wampserver

I have here this query:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT holderName,COUNT(holderName) as total, SUM(is_late) as total_late FROM (SELECT *,timestampdiff(minute, t1.startTime, t.IOTime) as is_late FROM (SELECT holderName, IODate, MIN(IOTime) as IOTime FROM tbl_records where IOStatus='Entry'AND IODate BETWEEN'"+from+"'AND'"+to+"' GROUP BY holderName, IODate) t JOIN tbl_emp t1 ON t.holderName = t1.name HAVING is_late > 0) AS t2 GROUP BY holderName  ORDER BY holderName, IODate");
```

this would return 3 values and i want it to put it in another table.

And I tried this one:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_temp values(null,name,total,total_late) SELECT holderName,COUNT(holderName) as total, SUM(is_late) as total_late FROM (SELECT *,timestampdiff(minute, t1.startTime, t.IOTime) as is_late FROM (SELECT holderName, IODate, MIN(IOTime) as IOTime FROM tbl_records where IOStatus='Entry'AND IODate BETWEEN'"+from+"'AND'"+to+"' GROUP BY holderName, IODate) t JOIN tbl_emp t1 ON t.holderName = t1.name HAVING is_late > 0) AS t2 GROUP BY holderName  ORDER BY holderName, IODate");
```

and i got errors in executing the insert!

Thanks!

Comment: the null in the insert is for the auto increment

Comment: Hope you are protecting against SQL injection. This is open for exploit. Also just post the error you are getting. If my suspicion is right you just need to remove the `null` in the values statement as you dont need to specify the auto number.

Comment: What errors do you get? You should try to use a prepared statement. Get the data from the resultset and pass them as parameters in the preparedstatement. Follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: already solved! shouldn't have put 'values' Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been great if you have put the error you are getting. One error I could spot for now is in your query syntax, you can't have the **VALUES**, it should be like :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp(name,total,total_late)
SELECT holderName,COUNT(holderName) as tot...
```

Have a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)